# What will happen if there are 2 methods with same signature. One native and second extension Method?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

What will happen if I create an Extension method (EM) with same signature as a native method.

**My Scenario**
I created an Extension Method

```
public static class EM
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this List<T> enu, Action<T> action)
    {            
        foreach (T item in enu)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

Now since List also has a function with same signature

```
public void ForEach(Action<T> action);
```

so for List I did

```
List<Label> re = new List<Label>();
re.ForEach(x => Foo(x));
```

This compiles and runs but it does not call my EM and instead calls its native method. I am sure it will not show that there are 2 overloads since for overloading there has to be some change in signtaure

[image]

**Queries**
Q1. Why is this happening?
Q2. If there were more parameters, then i could have changed parameter order and called it. But how do I make him call my EM with same number of parameters (This is a very simple Explaination of my problem. My EM could have been a complex one)?

Comment: `IEnumerable<Label> re = new List<Label>()` should do the trick, no?

Comment: @leppie: Your answer worked for `this IEnumerable<T>`. But now question has changed. Now the method takes `this List<T>`

Comment: I think this is an interesting complement of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655209/how-to-hide-a-member-method-by-an-extension-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# will always call the method on the class instead of calling the extension method.  I suggest adding something to the name of the method to distinguish it.  I personally use Ex at the end because it is short and reminds me that it is an extension method.

```
public static class EM
{
    public static void ForEachEx<T>(this List<T> enu, Action<T> action)
    {            
        foreach (T item in enu)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `before calling ` It should be `instead of calling`